# Conditionals and techniques other than iteration for python 3 pandas' dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I am continuing to work on my pandas skills and have run up against some difficult problems.  This problem involves two dataframes df1 and df2.  df1 contains event times and the corresponding details of each event.  df2 contains a time period established by a start time and a stop time.

GOAL:

1. group all events by time period.
2. check if the count is increasing within the time period AND if all the codes are the same for the time period
3. create a new column in df2 and return True to that column if BOTH pieces from part 2 are True and False if they are not or there are no events during the period.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
    
df1 = {'Event':  ['2020-12-01 00:10:22', '2020-12-01 00:15:11','2020-12-01 00:18:00',
                  '2020-12-01 00:31:00', '2020-12-01 00:54:00' , '2020-12-01 01:01:00' ,
                  '2020-12-01 01:19:00' , '2020-12-01 01:23:00' , '2020-12-01 01:24:00' ,
                  '2020-12-01 01:56:00' , '2020-12-01 21:02:00', '2020-12-01 02:41:00', 
                  '2020-12-01 02:44:00' , '2020-12-01 03:19:00' ,'2020-12-01 03:22:00' , 
                  '2020-12-01 03:49:00' , '2020-12-01 05:24:00' ,'2020-12-01 05:56:00' , 
                  '2020-12-01 08:02:00'
                   ] , 
       'Count' : [1 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 5 , 
                  3 , 7 , 9 , 10 , 1 , 
                  2 , 5 , 6 , 10 , 5 , 
                  6 ,7 , 8 , 3] ,
      'Code' : ['A' , 'A' , 'A' , 'A' , 'B' , 
                'B' , 'B' , 'B' , 'B' , 'B' , 
                'C' , 'C' , 'C' , 'C' , 'C' , 
                'D' , 'D' , 'D' , 'D']
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1 , columns = ['Event' , 'Count' , 'Code'])

df1['Event'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Event'])

df

    Event   Count   Code
0   2020-12-01 00:10:22     1   A
1   2020-12-01 00:15:11     2   A
2   2020-12-01 00:18:00     4   A
3   2020-12-01 00:31:00     2   A
4   2020-12-01 00:54:00     5   B
5   2020-12-01 01:01:00     3   B
6   2020-12-01 01:19:00     7   B
7   2020-12-01 01:23:00     9   B
8   2020-12-01 01:24:00     10  B
9   2020-12-01 01:56:00     1   B
10  2020-12-01 21:02:00     2   C
11  2020-12-01 02:41:00     5   C
12  2020-12-01 02:44:00     6   C
13  2020-12-01 03:19:00     10  C
14  2020-12-01 03:22:00     5   C
15  2020-12-01 03:49:00     6   D
16  2020-12-01 05:24:00     7   D
17  2020-12-01 05:56:00     8   D
18  2020-12-01 08:02:00     3   D
```

creating df2 code :

```
df2 = {'Start Time' : ['2020-12-01 00:00:00', '2020-12-01 00:30:00','2020-12-01 01:30:00',
                    '2020-12-01 02:30:00', '2020-12-01 03:30:00' , '2020-12-01 04:30:00' ,
                    '2020-12-01 05:30:00' , '2020-12-01 07:30:00' , '2020-12-01 10:30:00' ,
                    '2020-12-01 15:00:00' , '2020-12-02 21:00:00'] ,
       'End Time' : ['2020-12-01 00:30:00', '2020-12-01 01:30:00','2020-12-01 02:30:00',
                    '2020-12-01 03:30:00', '2020-12-01 04:30:00' , '2020-12-01 05:30:00' ,
                    '2020-12-01 07:30:00' , '2020-12-01 10:30:00' , '2020-12-01 15:00:00' ,
                    '2020-12-01 21:00:00' , '2020-12-02 00:00:00']
       
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2 , columns = ['Start Time' , 'End Time'])

df2['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start Time'])
df2['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['End Time'])

df2

    Start Time  End Time
0   2020-12-01 00:00:00     2020-12-01 00:30:00
1   2020-12-01 00:30:00     2020-12-01 01:30:00
2   2020-12-01 01:30:00     2020-12-01 02:30:00
3   2020-12-01 02:30:00     2020-12-01 03:30:00
4   2020-12-01 03:30:00     2020-12-01 04:30:00
5   2020-12-01 04:30:00     2020-12-01 05:30:00
6   2020-12-01 05:30:00     2020-12-01 07:30:00
7   2020-12-01 07:30:00     2020-12-01 10:30:00
8   2020-12-01 10:30:00     2020-12-01 15:00:00
9   2020-12-01 15:00:00     2020-12-01 21:00:00
10  2020-12-01 21:00:00     2020-12-02 00:00:00
```

Strategy:

My strategy is to use [pd.Dataframe.between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) and then a lambda function for the conditional statement checks but I cannot seem to make it work.

Below is the desired output:

```
    Start Time  End Time    Test
0   2020-12-01 00:00:00     2020-12-01 00:30:00     True
1   2020-12-01 00:30:00     2020-12-01 01:30:00     False
2   2020-12-01 01:30:00     2020-12-01 02:30:00     True
3   2020-12-01 02:30:00     2020-12-01 03:30:00     False
4   2020-12-01 03:30:00     2020-12-01 04:30:00     True
5   2020-12-01 04:30:00     2020-12-01 05:30:00     True
6   2020-12-01 05:30:00     2020-12-01 07:30:00     True
7   2020-12-01 07:30:00     2020-12-01 10:30:00     True
8   2020-12-01 10:30:00     2020-12-01 15:00:00     False
9   2020-12-01 15:00:00     2020-12-01 21:00:00     False
10  2020-12-02 21:00:00     2020-12-02 00:00:00     False
```

Comment: "Cannot seem to make it work", could you share the code that you have tried so far, and what the problem is with that code.

Comment: I have tried a number of different things but the general strategy is to use between_time and then either .apply in this general structure:  df['new column name'] = df['column name'].apply(lambda x: 'value if condition is met' if x condition else 'value if condition is not met') but that only seems to work for one condition.

Comment: @kdbaseball8 I guess the output for the row with index `2` should be `True` and for index `10` it should be `False`

Comment: no that event is just out of order but should be applied to the correct time slot

Comment: sorry you are correct, I will change that, it was an entry error

Comment: @kdbaseball8 No problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom function that yields a boolean value based on the specified conditions. Here we have used [`Series.is_monotonic_increasing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_monotonic_increasing.html) to check if `Count` in increasing and [`Series.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) to check if all codes are same for the given time period:

```
def f():
    for x, y in df2.to_numpy():
        s = df1[df1['Event'].between(x, y)]
        yield s['Count'].is_monotonic_increasing & s['Code'].nunique() == 1

df2['Test'] = list(f())
```

Result:

```
            Start Time            End Time   Test
0  2020-12-01 00:00:00 2020-12-01 00:30:00   True
1  2020-12-01 00:30:00 2020-12-01 01:30:00  False
2  2020-12-01 01:30:00 2020-12-01 02:30:00   True
3  2020-12-01 02:30:00 2020-12-01 03:30:00  False
4  2020-12-01 03:30:00 2020-12-01 04:30:00   True
5  2020-12-01 04:30:00 2020-12-01 05:30:00   True
6  2020-12-01 05:30:00 2020-12-01 07:30:00   True
7  2020-12-01 07:30:00 2020-12-01 10:30:00   True
8  2020-12-01 10:30:00 2020-12-01 15:00:00  False
9  2020-12-01 15:00:00 2020-12-01 21:00:00  False
10 2020-12-02 21:00:00 2020-12-02 00:00:00  False
```

Comment: Thank You Shubham!  That works and completely different than how I was thinking I should solve the problem.

Comment: @kdbaseball8 Happy coding!